# List firstWhere Bad state: No element

Tags: dart

I am running **`list.firstWhere`** and this is sometimes throwing an exception:

```
Bad State: No element

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
#0      _ListBase&Object&ListMixin.firstWhere (dart:collection/list.dart:148:5)
```

I do not understand what this means an also could not identify the issue by looking [at the source](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/master/sdk/lib/collection/list.dart#L148).

My `firstWhere` looks like this:

```
list.firstWhere((element) => a == b);
```

Comment: In my case it generally happens due to no element/data i,e empty values on variable.
  So to avoid these issues , assign some values to variable like this.

     var artist = 'Artist'.obs;

Answer (score 415, accepted):

This will happen when there is no matching element, i.e. when `a == b` is never true for any of the elements in `list` **and** the *optional parameter `orElse`* is not specified.

You can also specify `orElse` to handle the situation:

```dart
list.firstWhere((a) => a == b, orElse: () => print('No matching element.'));
```

If you want to return `null` instead when there is no match, you can also do that with `orElse`:

```dart
list.firstWhere((a) => a == b, orElse: () => null);
```

---

[`package:collection`](https://pub.dev/packages/collection) also contains a convenience extension method for the `null` case (which should also work better with null safety):

```dart
import 'package:collection/collection.dart';

list.firstWhereOrNull((element) => element == other);
```

See [`firstWhereOrNull`](https://pub.dev/documentation/collection/latest/collection/IterableExtension/firstWhereOrNull.html) for more information. Thanks to [@EdwinLiu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66881439/6509751) for pointing it out.

Comment: `list.firstWhere((element) => a == b, orElse: () => null);` allows you to silently return null.

Answer (score 22):

Now you can import `package:collection` and use the extension method firstWhereOrNull

```
import 'package:collection/collection.dart';

void main() {

  final myList = [1, 2, 3];

  final myElement = myList.firstWhereOrNull((a) => a == 4);

  print(myElement); // null
}
```

Answer (score 17):

`firstWhere` retuns the newList which generated based on the condition

```
void main() {
  List<String> list = ['red', 'yellow', 'pink', 'blue'];
  var newList = list.firstWhere((element) => element == 'green', 
      orElse: () => 'No matching color found');
  print(newList);
}
```

**Output:**

```
No matching color found
```

**OR**

```
 void main() {
      List<String> list = ['red', 'yellow', 'pink', 'blue'];
      var newList = list.firstWhere((element) => element == 'blue', 
          orElse: () => 'No matching color found');
      print(newList);
    }
```

**Output:**

```
blue
```

If orElse is not defined in the code and the wrong item gets searched which doesn't exist in the list then it shows BadStateException

```
 void main() {
      List<String> list = ['red', 'yellow', 'pink', 'blue'];
      var newList = list.firstWhere((element) => element == 'green');
      print(newList);
    }
```

**Output:**

```
Uncaught Error: Bad state: No element
```

Answer (score 4):

The `firstWhere()` implementation looks something like below:

```
  E firstWhere(bool test(E element), {E orElse()?}) {
    for (E element in this) {
      if (test(element)) return element;
    }
    if (orElse != null) return orElse();
    throw IterableElementError.noElement();
  }
```

So as you can see, if the `orElse` arg is defined the method will use that and will not throw any exception if none of the elements match the condition. So use the below code to handle the erro case:

```
list.firstWhere((element) => a == b, orElse: () => null); // To return null if no elements match
list.firstWhere((element) => a == b, orElse: () => print('No elements matched the condition'));
```

Answer (score 4):

On dart **`2.10`** there is a new feature called `null-safety` and can do magic for you when you have a list of objects and you want to do something to one particular object's property:

```
class User {
   String name;
   int age;

  User(this.name, this.age);

   @override
   String toString() {
   return  'name:$name, age:$age';
   }

}

void main() {
  List<User?> users = [User("Ali", 20), User("Mammad", 40)];
  print(users.toString()); // -> [name:Ali, age:20, name:Mammad, age:40]
  // modify user age who it's name is Ali:
  users.firstWhere((element) => element?.name == "Ali")?.age = 30;
  print(users.toString()); // -> [name:Ali, age:30, name:Mammad, age:40]
  // modify a user that doesn't exist:
  users.firstWhere((element) => element?.name == "AliReza", orElse: ()=> null)?.age = 30; // doesn't find and works fine
  print(users.toString()); // -> [name:Ali, age:30, name:Mammad, age:40]

}
```

Answer (score 4):

I had this problem when I used `.first`propery with an empty array.

To fixed this, just check if the array is empty or not before using `.first`:

##### Example:

```dart
 OrderAddress(
        address: addressRepository.items.isEmpty
            ? null
            : addressRepository.items.first,
      ),
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You need to check the itemCount parameter of relevant list.
For example:
itemCount: snapshot.data?.docs.length
if your itemcount is just like above, you must check nullsafety first and after that check nullability. You itemcount may be like as follows.
itemCount: snapshot.data?.docs.length ?? 0,

of course in StreamBuilder you can use singleOrNull :
snapshot.data!.docs.singleOrNull!['X'],