# Flutter show image only if it exists in array

Tags: image, flutter, dart, widget

Inside my `widget` I have some `images`. These `images` have a `position`. I would like to check if an image with a certain position exists, show it. Else the `child` of my `GestureDetector` should simply be nothing.

This is what I tried:

```
child: GestureDetector(
        onTap: () => print("tapped 1"),
        onScaleStart: (details) {
          _startingFocalPoint.value = details.focalPoint;
          _previousOffset.value = _offset.value;
          _previousZoom.value = _zoom.value;
        },
        onScaleUpdate: (details) {
          _zoom.value = _previousZoom.value * details.scale;
          final Offset normalizedOffset =
              (_startingFocalPoint.value - _previousOffset.value) /
                  _previousZoom.value;
          _offset.value =
              details.focalPoint - normalizedOffset * _zoom.value;
        },
        child: widget.images.where(
                    (image) => image.position == ImagePosition.ONE) !=
                null
            ? ClipPath(
                clipper: _Position1ClipperImage(),
                child: Transform(
                  transform: Matrix4.identity()
                    ..translate(_offset.value.dx, _offset.value.dy)
                    ..scale(_zoom.value),
                  child: Image.asset(
                      widget.images
                          .firstWhere(
                            (image) => image.position == ImagePosition.ONE,
                          )
                          .path,
                      width: widget.width,
                      height: widget.width,
                      fit: BoxFit.fill),
                ),
              )
            : null,
      ),
```

But if there is no `image` with `ImagePosition.ONE` , I get a `Bad State: No elemnt`- Error.

What am I missing here?

Let me know if you need any more details!

Comment: refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/63300764/5106574

Comment: What you exactly want to do? You want to check image Position or image nullability?

Comment: @JiteshMohite kind of but not exactly

Comment: @Kudos If the image exists, there should be a child with that image. Else there should be no child. I  updated my qeustion

Answer (score 0):

Try to update `: null` at the end with `: SizedBox.shrink()`. I think the problem is that you are giving a `null` as a `child` to the `GestureDetector` in case there is no image

Comment: Can you share the stacktrace?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not actually because not having all the stack trace of your error but try replacing null by empty `Container()` if still not work please provide all your stacktrace for further help